# What is the difference between intercepting post-save and intercepting pre-commit in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In other words, what is the difference between overriding the `SaveChangesInterceptor.SavedChanges()` and `DbTransactionInterceptor.TransactionCommitting()`?
I would like to store audit logs at this point (in another storage location, not in the db), so my question is what is the difference between these 2 points in code execution?
Documentation of interceptors: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors)

Comment: `SaveChanges` called very time you call the savechanges method in your context but that doesn't mean those entities are written into the database if a transaction going on where a rollback operation is possible, so you need to use both to make sure audit is consistent

Comment: It'll become obvious when you try to write your code. Without a concrete case this question is too vague to answer. It depends very much on what you want to log. For one, only `SaveChangesInterceptor` will provide acces to modified entities.

Comment: Right, so I'm specifically waiting until after Save to log newly created items, since they do not have ids until they are saved. Assuming I hold onto them by reference, what would be the difference between doing the work in SavedChanges() vs TransactionCommitting()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is clearly a difference, because if I was not using a transaction there would be no pre-commit stage. In my case, since I *am* using a transaction and I know I need to wait until after the database saves to store the audit logs (since I need IDs for newly created entities), I use the post save interceptor - `SaveChangesInterceptor.SavedChanges()`.

Comment: It's unclear how this answers the question. Nobody said there's no difference. You're using two different interceptors, doing two different things. As for `I am using a transaction` what does this mean? SaveChanges persists all pending changes using a database transaction already (assuming the database has transactions). Did you create another transaction over the existing one?

Comment: `if I was not using a transaction there would be no pre-commit stage.` there's no such scenario because SaveChanges itself uses transactions. Then SaveChanges eventually commits that transaction, `DbTransactionInterceptor` will be used to execute custom logic before or after committing